Immediate FetchRequest in CoreData with CloudKit
I'm utilizing CoreData with CloudKit to store workout data in SwiftUI for the watch app. However, when a new data entry is stored in the WorkoutLogItemDetailView and I return to the CurrentLogView, it takes some time – a few seconds to a minute – for the updated data to appear on the ScrollView.
To be honest, I'm a bit puzzled by the FetchRequest mechanism. How can I adjust my code to ensure that data is fetched immediately when the view loads?
struct CurrentLogView: View {
    @Binding var selectedLog: CDLog?
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: CDLogItem.fetch(), animation: .bouncy) var logItems

    
    init (viewSelector: Binding<TargetView>, selectedLog: Binding<CDLog?>) {
        self._selectedLog = selectedLog
        var request = CDLogItem.fetch()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "log == %@", selectedLog.wrappedValue! as CVarArg)
        self._logItems = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: request)
    }

    private var groupedLogItems: [GroupedLogItems] {
        // I create a new array from the fetched logItems
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            ForEach(groupedLogItems, id: \.id) { group in
                // load logItems
            }
        }

        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                // navigate to view where new data is stored
                NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutLogItemDetailView(selectedWorkout: selectedGroup.workoutName, selectedLog: selectedLog)) {
                    Image(systemName:"record.circle.fill")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension CDLogItem {
    static func fetch(_ predicate: NSPredicate = .all) -> NSFetchRequest<CDLogItem> {
        let request = CDLogItem.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CDLogItem.orderId_, ascending: true),
                                   NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CDLogItem.uuid_, ascending: false)]
        request.predicate = predicate
        return request
    }
}

